# Include stage environment in ansible

Tags: ansible

I want to deploy staging and production environment using ansible. All components are same for both staging and production except few configurations. So i created following files

```
 group_vars
  - all.yml
  - production.yml
  - staging.yml
```

Whenever i run `ansible-playbook`, it loads configuration from all.yml. But i also want to load either `production.yml` or `staging.yml`.

How do i include this configuration when run ansible playbook command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should actually work out of the box, given you have your hosts grouped in your inventory.

So let's say your inventory looks like this:

```
[production]
host.a
host.b

[staging]
host.c
host.d
```

And then you'd have the following yaml files, relative to your playbook:

- group_vars/all
- group_vars/production
- group_vars/staging

The vars from all matching groups will be loaded. And of course additionally the `all` file.

Instead of files, the group names could also be directories and all included yaml files would then be loaded.

---

Update after discussion in comments:

So if your inventory for production looks like this:

```
[redisServers]
host.a
host.b

[apiServers]
host.c
host.d

[SQLServers]
host.e
host.f
```

Then you'd add another group `production`. To not repeat all the hostnames you can create a [group of groups](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html#groups-of-groups-and-group-variables), like so:

```
[production:children]
redisServers
apiServers
SQLServers
```

Comment: But my inventory files has group like `[redisServers], [apiServers],[SQLServers]` something like this. I could not group based on stage environment.

Comment: A host can be member of multiple groups. It can be in the `redisServers` and the `production` group and all group_vars will be applied accordingly. Depending on complexity of your project though, it might be better to separate the inventory by environment. This could be additionally seen as a security measure, because you definitely do not want to do anything to your prod hosts when you run Ansible against the staging environment.

Comment: Yes, as you said. i prefer to have different inventory for each environments. In that case, how do i include appropriate configuration file

Comment: So you have a `production` and a `staging` inventory file. Then each of those files should have a group with the same name holding _all_ the hosts. I'll add an example above.